# ImportError with Django 1.8.5 and Celery

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, celery

I'm trying to get Celery to work Django, following the official documentation, and the video located here: https://godjango.com/63-deferred-tasks-and-scheduled-jobs-with-celery-31-django-17-and-redis/

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but this always results in an ImportError.

The project is called "clubmgmt"

Contents of "clubmgmt/celery.py" :

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
import django
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'clubmgmt.settings')
django.setup()

app = Celery('clubmgmt')

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

Contents of "clubmgmt/__init__.py"

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from clubmgmt.celery import app as celery_app
```

the task is defined in an app called "activation"

Contents of "activation/tasks.py":

```
from activation.models import Activation
from django.conf import settings
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from clubmgmt.celery import app

__author__ = 'jeroenjacobs'

@app.task
def send_activation_mail(activation_pk):
    activation = Activation.objects.get(pk=activation_pk)
    mail = activation.user.email

    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg['Subject'] = "Please activate your account"
    msg['From'] = settings.SMTP_SENDER_ADDRESS
    msg['To'] = mail
    ...
```

I always receive the following error:

```
(clubmgmt) > $ python manage.py runserver                                                                                                                      [±master ●●●]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/jeroenjacobs/.pyenv/versions/clubmgmt/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 351, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/jeroenjacobs/.pyenv/versions/clubmgmt/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 303, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/Users/jeroenjacobs/.pyenv/versions/clubmgmt/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Users/jeroenjacobs/.pyenv/versions/clubmgmt/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/Users/jeroenjacobs/.pyenv/versions/clubmgmt/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/Users/jeroenjacobs/.pyenv/versions/3.4.3/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2212, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/jeroenjacobs/PycharmProjects/clubmgmt/clubmgmt/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from clubmgmt.celery import app as celery_app
  File "/Users/jeroenjacobs/PycharmProjects/clubmgmt/clubmgmt/celery.py", line 9, in <module>
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/jeroenjacobs/.pyenv/versions/clubmgmt/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/jeroenjacobs/.pyenv/versions/clubmgmt/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 115, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/Users/jeroenjacobs/PycharmProjects/clubmgmt/activation/apps.py", line 10, in ready
    import activation.handlers
  File "/Users/jeroenjacobs/PycharmProjects/clubmgmt/activation/handlers.py", line 6, in <module>
    from activation.utils import create_or_update_activation
  File "/Users/jeroenjacobs/PycharmProjects/clubmgmt/activation/utils.py", line 2, in <module>
    from activation.tasks import send_activation_mail
  File "/Users/jeroenjacobs/PycharmProjects/clubmgmt/activation/tasks.py", line 7, in <module>
    from clubmgmt.celery import app
ImportError: cannot import name 'app'
```

Can someone please explain me why "app" cannot be imported?

BTW: This is tested under python 3.4. Going back to Python 2 is not an option, so please don't suggest this as a solution. If Celery is not Python3 compatible, are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `clubmgmt.celery.app` tries to import `clubmgm.celery.app` resulting in a circular import.

If you look at your stack trace `clubmgmt.__init__` imports `clubmgmt.celery.app`, which in turns makes `django` run its setup routine which ends up triggering the import of `clubmgmt.activation.apps` which at some point through `clubmgmt.activation.tasks` imports `clubmgmt.celery.app` again, while it's still being imported, resulting in an `ImportError`.

Removing that import from `__init__.py` will definitely solve the problem, but if you still need it there, you might be able to do something with `activation/apps.py` instead.

One thing I've learned so far is that 90% of the time `ImportError` occurs due to circular imports, the other 10% is due to misspelling, or something like that.